# Grouping columns to form time series data (Python)

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df which looks like this

| restaurant | opentime | closetime | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABX | 10:00:00 | 21:00:00 | Gold |
| BWZ | 13:00:00 | 14:00:00 | Silver |
| GTW | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 | Gold |

I want to create a time series dataframe df2 based on the start and end date of my choice which shows the restaurants open by group and indexed by all the hours. In this case, I have taken a start date of May 17th 2021 and an end date of May 18th 2021. The final dataframe should look like this

| Date | Gold | Silver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-17 9:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-17 10:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-05-17 11:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-05-17 12:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-05-17 13:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-17 14:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-17 15:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| ...................... | ...... | ........ |
| ...................... | ...... | ........ |
| 2021-05-18 23:00:00 | 0 | 0 |

If the Date part is too difficult to recreate, then just time would also help in such a way it looks like this

| Time | Gold | Silver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 10:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 11:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 12:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 13:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 14:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 15:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| ...................... | ...... | ........ |
| ...................... | ...... | ........ |
| 23:00:00 | 0 | 0 |

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your first dataframe does not take the date into account, the result for 2021-05-17 is the same as 2021-05-18, as 2021-05-19 and so on. I don't understand the logic.

Comment: Yes, it would be the same for all dates, However, the result has to be in this format because the next step is to actually join this with some actual varying time-series features.

Comment: If you know a code to create the data frame without the date but just the time for 24 hours. That would also help a lot

Comment: Do you need business hours or 24h is good for you?

Comment: 24h is also good. Both option is okay!

Answer (score 0):

**First part: Time**

Create a list that contains all hours between `opentime` and `closetime` then explode the list into rows and group by `(time, group)` and count values for each group.

**Second part: Date**

Create a datetime index that contains all hours between `start_date` and `end_date`. Transform as a series and set time as index.

**Last part: Merge Date and Time**

Merge `dfd` (date dataframe) and `dft` (time dataframe) together to get the groups for each datetime.

```
start_date = "2021-05-17"
end_date = "2021-05-18"

# compute hours between opentime and closetime
df["time"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["opentime"],
                                              x["closetime"],
                                              freq="1H").time, axis="columns")

# value count by time and group
dft = df.explode("time").value_counts(["time", "group"]).unstack("group")

# create datetime index between start_date and end_date
dti = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(start_date),
                    end=pd.to_datetime(end_date) + pd.DateOffset(days=1),
                    closed="left", freq="1H", name="datetime")
dfd = dti.to_series(index=dti.time)

# merge date and time dataframes
out = pd.merge(dfd, dft, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left") \
        .set_index("datetime").sort_index().fillna(0)
```

```
>>> out
                     Gold  Silver
datetime
2021-05-17 00:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 01:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 02:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 03:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 04:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 05:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 06:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 07:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 08:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 09:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 10:00:00   2.0     0.0
2021-05-17 11:00:00   2.0     0.0
2021-05-17 12:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 13:00:00   1.0     1.0
2021-05-17 14:00:00   1.0     1.0
2021-05-17 15:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 16:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 17:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 18:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 19:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 20:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 21:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-17 22:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-17 23:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 00:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 01:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 02:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 03:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 04:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 05:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 06:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 07:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 08:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 09:00:00   0.0     0.0
2021-05-18 10:00:00   2.0     0.0
2021-05-18 11:00:00   2.0     0.0
2021-05-18 12:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 13:00:00   1.0     1.0
2021-05-18 14:00:00   1.0     1.0
2021-05-18 15:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 16:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 17:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 18:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 19:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 20:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 21:00:00   1.0     0.0
2021-05-18 22:00:00   0.0     0.0
```

```
>>> dfd.index
Index([00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00:00, 06:00:00,
       07:00:00, 08:00:00, 09:00:00, 10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00, 13:00:00,
       14:00:00, 15:00:00, 16:00:00, 17:00:00, 18:00:00, 19:00:00, 20:00:00,
       21:00:00, 22:00:00, 23:00:00, 00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00,
       04:00:00, 05:00:00, 06:00:00, 07:00:00, 08:00:00, 09:00:00, 10:00:00,
       11:00:00, 12:00:00, 13:00:00, 14:00:00, 15:00:00, 16:00:00, 17:00:00,
       18:00:00, 19:00:00, 20:00:00, 21:00:00, 22:00:00, 23:00:00],
      dtype='object')

>>> dft.index
Index([10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00, 13:00:00, 14:00:00, 15:00:00, 16:00:00,
       17:00:00, 18:00:00, 19:00:00, 20:00:00, 21:00:00],
      dtype='object', name='time')
```

Comment: Okay! Thanks awaiting your response!

Comment: @Datalearner. I updated my answer. I hope my explanation is clear.